# Como ejecutar aplicaciones Java(.jar) sin instalar JDK - JRE en el computador?

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas tardes, sucede que realicé una aplicacion Java que usa .jar externos para reportes y otras funciones de la aplicacion. Tambien use SQLite.
NetBeans por defecto crea una carpeta llamada 'dist' que cotiene el nameapp.jar ejecutable; y la carpeta 'lib' en donde estan las librerias que necesita la aplicacion.
La aplicacion la quiero dejar de tal manera que cualquier usuario la descargue en formato .exe, la pueda instalar (next-next-next- como cualquier programa) y se le cree un acceso directo en el escritorio.
Tengo entendido que con InnoSetup se puede crear instaladores, y para hacer que funcione la aplicacion sin que el computador tenga instalado Java, hay que copiar toda la carpeta JRE de nuestro Java en donde compilamos etc..
Hay que tener en cuenta que cuando encuentra un archivo .jar, y no esta instaladoo Java en el computador, pues e icono de ese .jar sera en el de Winrar, en fin.. Espero me puedan ayudar, GRACIAS!

Comment: **Cuál es tu duda o problema?** Por cómo está formateada la pregunta, se puede ver como un manual o instrucciones, no como algo que hay que resolver; si puedes formatear tu pregunta para incluir errores, dudas, un poco de código... Algo que nos deje entender, qué esperas/necesitas y lo que obtienes en cambio. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para tener las mejores preguntas y la mejor asistencia. Bienvenido a SO! ;)

Comment: Un poco amplia tu pregunta, pero  es posible, te recomiendo usar el JRE portable de [aqui](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) recuerda que para ejecutar un jar es necesario usar un comando desde el JRE portable `ruta/a/java.exe -jar tujar.jar` que puedes guardar en un archivo `.bat` y despues guardar tu proyecto y el java portable usando no sé, algo como: [Smart Install Maker](http://es.sminstall.com)

Comment: Rolin Azmitia: si señor tienes razon, en realidad queria encontrarme con alguien que haya tenido una experiencia en ejecutar aplicaciones en equipos donde no esté instalado java en el sistema operativo.  Mi duda es la misma, como ejecutar aplicaciones Java(.jar) sin instalar Java en el equipo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para poder usar aplicaciones `Java` **(jar)** en diferentes equipos hay de dos maneras:

- Instalar el JRE (java) en cada equipo de forma global (lo más común) ó
- Usando un paquete portable de JRE (como [jPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable)) dentro de un proyecto de instalación de Windows.

Para el segundo caso es necesario tener en cuenta algunas cosas:

- Tener el paquete portable descomprimido y localizado el archivo java.exe
- Tener un programa para crear proyectos de instalación de Windows ([Smart Install Maker](http://es.sminstall.com/))
- Generar un archivo de instrucciones del sistema (.bat o .cmd) para ejecutar el archivo jar.
- Guardar TODOS los archivos dentro de un proyecto de instalación que generará un instalador .exe

Aqui un ejemplo del árbol de directorios:

```
Tuapp/
├── Java Portable
│   └── bin
│       └── java.exe
├── libs
├── Tuapp.bat
└── TuJAR.jar
```

Para ejecutar tu jar debes indicarle al sistema la ruta del java portable y la ruta de tu jar y guardarlo en un archivo .bat por ejemplo:

```
@echo off
"%cd%\JavaPortable\bin\java.exe" -jar "TuJAR.jar"
```

Con eso y si pasas toda tu carpeta a otra computadora, podrás ejecutar el archivo `Tuapp.bat` para ejecutar tu aplicación java.

Si quieres agregar un icono debes convertir el .bat a un EXE ([Bat2Exe](http://www.f2ko.de/es/b2e.php)) y generar el instalador apuntando a ese EXE dentro del proyecto del creador de instalación.

Comment: Exacto! Asi mismo... Aunque no es obligatorio el JPortable, pues se puede copiar la carpeta JRE que se creo al momento de la instalacion de java.. lo importa es el codigo en el .bat que especifique bien el java.exe

Aunque Smart Install Maker parece ser de pago. Intentare con Inno Setup.

Gracias!

Comment: Amigo, y para cerrar o minimizar la ventana MS-DOS de windows como se hace?

Comment: yo especialmente uso bat2exe para agregar el icono de la aplicacion y tiene la opción de ocultar la ventana del DOS

Comment: Si, eso estoy usando pero hay varios modelos o programas de bat2exe, me he encontrado con 3 distintos... De todas formas ya lo solucione agregando la funcion start y ejecutando el javaw.exe que se encarga de no mostrar la consola a diferencia del java.exe. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar jPortable para realizar los que buscas: [jPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable).

Te en cuenta si hablamos solo de ejecutar no es necesario el JDK (Java Develoment Kit), ya que el encargado de la ejecución es el JRE.

Comment: Exacto si señor, los ficheros que se encargan de que el .jar funcione estan en el JRE... Pero hay un detalle, y es cuando se quiere ejecutar la aplicacion .jar haciendo doble clik... Pues windows al no tener instalado java, no sabrá que el archivo .jar pertenece a java, por lo tanto le asignara el icono de winrar o el compresor de archivos que este instalado en la maquina... Es por eso toca crear un .bat asignando los parametros de Java asi.
set HOME=%CD%
set JAVA_HOME=%HOME%\jre
set VM=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe